# How to select multiple select statement results as a one result?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to select multiple select * statement results in one result window not separately?

Like

```
select * from employee where name like '%shah%' 


select * from employee where name like '%reddy%'
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use or

```
select * from employee where name like '%reddy%'   or name like '%shah%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union

```
select * from employee where name like '%shah%' 
union
select * from employee where name like '%reddy%'
```

Comment: I have more than 200 records.

Comment: @TirathSingh 200 records are nothing for a database. Some databases are even optimized for millions of records. Note that `union` merges the result and only returns distinct rows. Use `union all` of you want all rows (even duplicates).

Comment: Hi Chriz, I'm getting results but I also want this in sequence like the query i execute first should give result one first row of result and so on...